# Prove that a dynamical system $(X,T)$ is transitive and $X$ is finite then for any two points $x,y$ there is $n$ such that $T^n(x)=y$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that a dynamical system $(X,T)$ is transitive and $X$ is finite then for any two points $x,y$ there is $n$ such that $T^n(x)=y$.

As far as I could understand, if $(X,T)$ is transitive and suppose $x,y \in X$, then $xTy=xTx$. What kind of clues does finite $X$ give us here? To show that $T^n(x)=y$, do I need to show that $T(x) =y$, $T^2(x)=y$, ... , $T^n(x) = y$?.

Comment: "... then $xTy=xTy$"? What kind of transitive is this about? binary relation? group action?

Comment: My bad, I just fixed that! Do you have any hints?

Comment: Do you understand what do you mean by $T^n(x)=y$ , the definition I know is that there exists $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ such that $xTa_1,a_1Ta_2,\cdots,a_iTa_{i+1},\cdots,a_nTy$, can you define what fo you mean by $T^n(x)=y$ it's important

Comment: @Elaqqad, All I can think about $T^n(x) = y$ is that when $T$ is repeatedly applied to $x$ then the sequence of the map reaches the same point or limit that is $y$. What do you say?

Comment: what do you mean by " $T$ is repeatedly applied to $x$" you're thinkin about $T$ as a map and as a relation the two terms are different

Comment: ahh, then how do i get started?

Comment: You can look where did you find the question and then try to understand the definitions and the notations and then you will solve your problem

Comment: @Elaqqad $T^n(x)$ is the orbit of $x$. And $T^(x) = x$ then $x$ is the periodic point. But I don't really know what is $T^n(x)=y$ means.

Comment: Looks like some application of the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: @nayrb any more hints?

Comment: You need to clear up your question. It's not clear what $X$, $T$ or even transitive is in this question. Make it all much more precise.

Comment: $X$ is a set and $T$ is a map. $(X,T)$ is a dynamical system. Probably, transitive in this question would be topological transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dynamical system is typically a pair $(X,f)$ where $X$ is a set with some structure (measure space, topological space, manifold) of some kind and $f\colon X \to X$ is a structure-preserving (measure-preserving, continuous, smooth) map or flow. From the nature of the question, it seems like you're dealing with a discrete-time dynamical system, so your $T$ is one function, not a flow.

In the topological context, one conventionally says a system is *topologically transitive* if given any two nonempty open sets $U,V$ in $X$, there is some natural number $n$ such that $f^n(U)$ meets $V$ nontrivially. Here $f^n$ is a short-hand for the $n$-fold composition $f \circ \cdots \circ f$. The idea is that $f$ "eventually takes any point near any other point."

Typically, no topological spaces $X$ worse-behaved than Hausdorff are considered, so that a finite $X$ would be discrete. Working from that, topological transitivity would simply mean that for each pair of points $x,y$, there is some natural number such that 
$$f^n(x) = f(f(\cdots(f(x))\cdots)) = y.$$

So a reasonable *definition* of transitivity, for a dynamical system consisting of a mere *set* $X$ and function $T\colon X \to X$, is just the condition you described.

If $T$ is just a transitive *relation* on $X$, then it's not necessarily the case that $xTy$ for all $x,y \in X$; the equality relation $=$ is a counterexample.

Comment: thanks!, What do you mean by the condition that I described?

Comment: I mean that the second clause of the question, that for any $x,y \in X$ there exists an $n$ such that $f^n(x) = y$, is how I would guess that transitivity of a dynamical system $(X,f)$ with $x$ just a set was *defined*, so that I'm not sure how to answer your question.

Comment: Yeah, the relation should be topological transitive, then $T^n U \cap V $ is non-empty for $U,V \in X$. I don't really know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Is it not assumed the space is Hausdorff?

Comment: Yeah, I think so since I have never heard of the word "Hausdoff" throughout of my course.

Comment: Look up "Hausdorff space" on Wikipedia. It's critical: if you don't require it, you can give $X$ the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,X\}$ and then even the identity function is topologically transitive.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I required it though. Since $T^n U \cap V$ is non-empty, then $T^n x$  = $y$ for $x \in U$ and $y \in V$. I drew that conclusion based on the hints that you have provided.